# Data type doesn't match error in Sieve filter

Tags: classification, erdas-imagine, filter

I classified some land cover types in aerial image with Erdas Imagine, now I want to remove classification errors showing very small areas. I tried to use Sieve filter, but getting error notification "Data type doesn't match". I tried to use files with TIF and IMG extension. Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Always use Spatial Modeler! Here's a model that clumps and sieves - use the Threshold value to set the minimum clump size.
[image: ERDAS IMAGINE Clump and Sieve Model]

TIF and IMG should be fine; it may be that you're trying to work with a Continuous file; make sure the file you want to sieve is Thematic.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are sieving on the output of a clump. That is the only way it will work. There are pre-set models that you can use as a guide.